# Jquery code to filter input

Tags: jquery

I want to check if user input match content in a div, but am having problem when the input doesn't match anything i want to show `no match found` but is not working

how can i pass it to another id instead of using parent nod

```
//This is working
$(tageslist).find("h1:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
//But here i want to show this message in a different div
$(tageslist).find("h1:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))", function(){
$('#notfilter').html('Not found');
});
```

Is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. The `.find()` method does not accept two arguments. To check whether there was anything found use the `.length` property.
2. Your filter in `.find()` was searching for the opposite of what you actually wanted. It returned true whenever there was at least one element that doesn't contain your filter string even if there was one that does.

To fix these issues use this code:

```
if ($(tageslist).find("h1:Contains(" + filter + ")").length === 0) {
  $('#notfilter').html('Not found');
}
```

Comment: The code will run just fine but I just figuered it probably doesn't do what you actually want. To clarify: What you want is to show `Not found` when there is no `<h1>` element that contains the string stored in `filter`, right?

Comment: S yes that is what i want

Comment: @Alex Ok, check my updated answer. Now it should work as you want it to.